# Magento 2 - two language version, where is global css?

Tags: magento2, template, language

I have two language version, where is global **css**?

I changed file

> \htdocs\mgnt2\app\design\frontend\TemplateMonster\framework\web\css\style.css

But my changes are visible only one language version.

Comment: Have you created different theme folders for each language version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `pub/static/frontend` directory and then run the deploy command with your language code.

For example, if your language code is **nl_NL**, then run the deploy command as given below.

```
php -dmemory_limit=2G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy nl_NL -f
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Style works for my additional language but for my main language 'en_EN' doesn't work.

Comment: Have you run the deploy command with en_EN ?

Comment: Yes I do, but I had error

Comment: What error did you get? Check your log files and console tab in the browser.

Comment: I tried command with en_US - command works but style works only for additional language still

Comment: Remove pub/static/frontend/ directory and then try to run the command with the language code.